# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

```
Drop table if exists #populationpercentagevaccine
Create Table #populationpercentagevaccine
(
Continent nvarchar(255),
location nvarchar(255),
Date Datetime,
Population numeric,
New_vaccinations numeric,
cumulative_vaccine numeric
)
```

My table is executing perfect but that code **INSERT INTO** giving me problem

```
Insert into #populationpercentagevaccine
  select death.Continent, death.location, death.Date, death.Population, vaccine.New_vaccinations, 
    sum(convert(int,vaccine.new_vaccinations )) over(partition by death.location order by death.location, death.date) as cumulative_all_vaccine
```

I created table and inserting into that same table what is causing **Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition** that problem

Comment: cumulative_vaccine  is missing in Your insert statement. I just added the column.  @AshishYadav. the  number of columns in the table and insert statement is not matching. And also your query has no from clause and join s

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, and i have full query with join clause

Comment: if you can add the full query I can check. Sample answer is added. I used your given table

Comment: You just now edited the question.

Comment: i still see the old query actually

Comment: i tried every column by adding and also removing it. that's why i delete that column name and edit the question because i am still getting error.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 added support for `drop table if exists`. Are you sure that you are using/need a solution for (unsupported) SQL Server 2008?

Comment: yes because before that line i got one error that error is THE COLUMN NAME EXIST

Comment: i solve my problem by adding more columns and change that convert function into cast

Answer (score 1):

Your table columns and supplied columns in insert was not matching earlier.

```
   Insert into #populationpercentagevaccine
    select Continent, [location], [Date], [Population], New_vaccinations
    , sum(convert(int,new_vaccinations )) over(partition by [location] order by [location, [date]) as cumulative_all_vaccine 
    from #populationpercentagevaccine
```

This was your previous question:

```
 Create Table #populationpercentagevaccine
  (
   Continent nvarchar(255),
   location nvarchar(255),
   Date Datetime,
   Population numeric,
   New_vaccinations numeric,
   cumulative_vaccine numeric,
   cumulative_all_vaccine numeric
   )

 Insert into #populationpercentagevaccine
  select Continent, [location], [Date], [Population], New_vaccinations, cumulative_vaccine --this was missing earlier
  , sum(convert(int,new_vaccinations )) over(partition by [location] 
       order by [location, [date]) as cumulative_all_vaccine 
    from #populationpercentagevaccine
```

Answer (score 0):

your table has 7 columns, your query supplies values only for 6 of them.
either supply the value or insert the identity